# iOS opaque UIViewController on top of UINavigationController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I'm trying to present an opaque UIViewController from a UINavigationController. While the view is being animated, it is opaque just how I want it. When it is done animating, however, the background turns gray. I had this working when the previous view was a UIViewController. When I used a UINavigationController as the previous view I started having this issue.

Code to switch to view:

```
UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:STORYBOARD_IPHONE bundle:nil];
UIViewController *viewController = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:viewName];
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Code to make presented view opaque:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.7];
```

I think this might have something to do with the fact that the class that is presenting the view is not the UINavigationController, but a UIViewController within the UINavigationController. So I tried using self.navigationController presentViewController, but I got the same result.

How can I fix this so that the background remains opaque?

**The previous UINavigationController with embedded UIViewController:**

[image]

**What it looks like during animation:**

[image]

**What it looks like after animation:**

[image]

Comment: where you writing your background color code . is it in viewdidload? if it is then try to set backgoundcolor in viewwillappear.

Comment: Yes, I was setting that in viewDidLoad. I tried setting it in viewWillAppear, and viewDidAppear. I have the same problem.

Comment: You're setting your view to alpha 0.7 and wondering why you can see through it?  What's behind your view - probably a black background?  That and the 70% white is probably causing your gray.

Comment: @OwenHartnett It must be a black background, but why is it a black background? Why does it not show the UINavigationController behind it like it was when it was a UIViewController?

Comment: Does the UINavigationController have a view that has a white background behind it?  Or is that area transparent, and you're looking at the UIwindow behind it, which might have a black background?  Are you setting a rootviewController, or just calling init in the UINavigationController?

Comment: @OwenHartnett There is a method being called from an inherited class that I created that switches views. It runs the code that is shown in my question. That method is executed by a UIViewController embedded in a UINavigationController. The UIViewController is not plain, there are several custom ui elements. The UINavigationController by itself has no ui elements on it. It is plain. I'll post screenshots in a minute.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a routine I use regularly to see which views are sitting behind the view I'm interested in:

```
// useful debugging method - send it a view and it will log all subviews
// can be called from the debugger
- (void) viewAllSubviews:(UIView *) topView Indent:(NSString *) indent  {
    for (UIView * theView in [topView subviews]){
        NSLog(@"%@%@", indent, theView);
        if ([theView subviews] != nil)
            [self viewAllSubviews:theView Indent: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ",indent]];
    }
}
```

I usually put it somewhere where I can access it globally.  Call it like

```
[self viewAllSubviews:rootViewController.view Indent:@"  "];
```

It will print to the console the view tree rooted on whatever view you give it, and indent the subview according to level.  It should reveal just what you have behind your object of interest, and you can check frame coordinates for every view there.

This should give you a good clue as to what view is behind.